# SQL query that returns one unique row in one column based on values in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access, unique, distinct

I'm having trouble creating a query for the following goal: I want to return one of each unique value based on each unique group of values in another column.

This is the current setup I have in Access (using fake inputs for this question):

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
=======================
1      A    100
1      A    100
1      B    300
2      A    500
2      B    600
2      B    600
3      A    200
3      A    200
```

The desired output is the following:

```
Var1  Var2  Var3
=======================
1      A    100
1      B    300
2      A    500
2      B    600
3      A    200
```

Thanks for the help!

Edit:

I made an error in the Var2 column when I was originally asking the question.  Not all of the values in this case are different as I had them originally. Most of them are the same for each unique value in the Var1 column. So, I need, for each group of unique values in Var1, one of each unique value in Var2 for that specific group.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT`... your answer is even in the tag you used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT DISTINCT Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table

Comment: I made an error in the Var2 column when I was asking the question. I just edited it. Not all of the values in this case are different as I had them originally. Most of them are the same for each unique value in the Var1 column. So, I need, for each group of unique values in Var1, one of each unique value in Var2 for that specific group. Does that make sense?

Comment: This would still work according to what you have up in your original post.  It would display the output as you have it written.

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct function.try this query

```
select distinct Var1, Var2, Var3  from tablename
```

Or you can use group by

```
   select  Var1, Var2, Var3  from tablename group by  Var1, Var2, Var3
```

Comment: `distinct *`  doesn't make any sense. Any real world table will have a primary key and thus `distinct *` won't filter out any rows